# Q: How to write lotus script to automatically cc to some people for every email sent

Tags: lotusscript

My lotus version is 8.5.

The situation is, I am managing a group email, and each group member would like to keep track of every mail sent from this address. So how to automatically cc all these group members using lotus script or other methods?

Thanks!!

Comment: I like @torsten-link's answer but would question the goals here as well. This might not apply to what you need at all, but consider to instead ensure that all emails sent are automatically saved, that all group members have access to the database, and then *maybe* have a new/modified agent that periodically sends a list of new emails sent and received.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. First you need to disconnect the database from the template (whichever it was taken from) by deleting the master template from database properties, otherwise all your changes might be lost every other morning (if design task runs on server)

Then edit the forms **Memo**, **Reply** and **Reply with History** and change the *Input Translation*- Formula of the **EnterCopyTo** field like this:

Old formula:

```
@OptimizeMailAddress(EnterCopyTo)
```

New Formula:

```
_addGroup  := "NameOfTheGroupToAdd";
_addresses := @If( @IsMember( _addGroup; @ThisValue ); 
                   @ThisValue; 
                   @Trim( @ThisValue : _addGroup ) );
@OptimizeMailAddress(_addresses)
```

This formula will check, if the group is in the EnterCopyTo- Field and will add it, if it is missing.

Comment: Also, carefully document any changes you make to standard templates like the email template because otherwise the risks/impact of changing versions becomes much higher.